# Fine Uploader - Java Endpoint

Tags: jquery, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Does anyone have a full sample project using Fine Uploader with S3 and a Java endpoint?

I'm trying to send files using Fine Uploader directly to AWS S3 - I guess that something is wrong with my endpoint servlet or with setting my servlet on client side.

[Fine Uploader 5.6.0] Received an empty or invalid response from the server!
[Fine Uploader 5.6.0] Policy signing failed.  Received an empty or invalid response from the server!

My endpoint: Servlet Uploadfiles - http://www.example.com/uploadfiles

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.util.BinaryUtils;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class S3UploadsServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    final static String AWS_SECRET_KEY = "MY_SECRET_KEY";
    final static String AWS_PUBLIC_KEY = "MY_PUBLIC_KEY";

    // Main entry point for POST requests from Fine Uploader.  This currently assumes delete file requests use the
    // default method of DELETE, but that can be adjusted.
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException
    {
        if (req.getServletPath().endsWith("s3/signature"))
        {
            handleSignatureRequest(req, resp);
        }
        else if (req.getServletPath().endsWith("s3/success"))
        {
            handleUploadSuccessRequest(req, resp);
        }
    }

    // Main entry point for DELETE requests sent by Fine Uploader.
    @Override
    public void doDelete(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException
    {
        String key = req.getParameter("key");
        String bucket = req.getParameter("bucket");

        resp.setStatus(200);

        AWSCredentials myCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_PUBLIC_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
        AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(myCredentials);
        s3Client.deleteObject(bucket, key);
    }

    // Called by the main POST request handler if Fine Uploader has asked for an item to be signed.  The item may be a
    // policy document or a string that represents multipart upload request headers.
    private void handleSignatureRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException
    {
        resp.setStatus(200);

        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        JsonElement contentJson = jsonParser.parse(req.getReader());
        JsonObject jsonObject = contentJson.getAsJsonObject();

        if (req.getQueryString() != null && req.getQueryString().contains("v4=true")) {
            handleV4SignatureRequest(jsonObject, contentJson, req, resp);
        }
        else {
            handleV2SignatureRequest(jsonObject, contentJson, req, resp);
        }

        resp.setStatus(200);
    }

    private void handleV2SignatureRequest(JsonObject payload, JsonElement contentJson, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException{
        String signature;
        JsonElement headers = payload.get("headers");
        JsonObject response = new JsonObject();

        try
        {
            // If this is not a multipart upload-related request, Fine Uploader will send a policy document
            // as the value of a "policy" property in the request.  In that case, we must base-64 encode
            // the policy document and then sign it. The will include the base-64 encoded policy and the signed policy document.
            if (headers == null)
            {
                String base64Policy = base64EncodePolicy(contentJson);
                signature = sign(base64Policy);

                // Validate the policy document to ensure the client hasn't tampered with it.
                // If it has been tampered with, set this property on the response and set the status to a non-200 value.
                //response.addProperty("invalid", true);

                response.addProperty("policy", base64Policy);
            }

            // If this is a request to sign a multipart upload-related request, we only need to sign the headers,
            // which are passed as the value of a "headers" property from Fine Uploader.  In this case,
            // we only need to return the signed value.
            else
            {
                signature = sign(headers.getAsString());
            }

            response.addProperty("signature", signature);
            resp.getWriter().write(response.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            resp.setStatus(500);
        }
    }

    private void handleV4SignatureRequest(JsonObject payload, JsonElement contentJson, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException{
        String signature = null;
        JsonElement headers = payload.get("headers");
        JsonObject response = new JsonObject();

        try
        {
            // If this is not a multipart upload-related request, Fine Uploader will send a policy document
            // as the value of a "policy" property in the request.  In that case, we must base-64 encode
            // the policy document and then sign it. The will include the base-64 encoded policy and the signed policy document.
            if (headers == null)
            {
                String base64Policy = base64EncodePolicy(contentJson);
                JsonArray conditions = payload.getAsJsonArray("conditions");
                String credentialCondition = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < conditions.size(); i++) {
                    JsonObject condition = conditions.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
                    JsonElement value = condition.get("x-amz-credential");
                    if (value != null) {
                        credentialCondition = value.getAsString();
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Validate the policy document to ensure the client hasn't tampered with it.
                // If it has been tampered with, set this property on the response and set the status to a non-200 value.
//                response.addProperty("invalid", true);


                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+\\/(.+)\\/(.+)\\/s3\\/aws4_request");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(credentialCondition);
                matcher.matches();
                signature = getV4Signature(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), base64Policy);

                response.addProperty("policy", base64Policy);
            }

            // If this is a request to sign a multipart upload-related request, we only need to sign the headers,
            // which are passed as the value of a "headers" property from Fine Uploader.  In this case,
            // we only need to return the signed value.
            else
            {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+\\n.+\\n(\\d+)\\/(.+)\\/s3\\/aws4_request\\n(.+)", Pattern.DOTALL);
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(headers.getAsString());
                matcher.matches();
                String canonicalRequest = matcher.group(3);
                String hashedCanonicalRequest = hash256(canonicalRequest);
                String stringToSign = headers.getAsString().replaceAll("(?s)(.+s3\\/aws4_request\\n).+", "$1" + hashedCanonicalRequest);

                // Validate the policy document to ensure the client hasn't tampered with it.
                // If it has been tampered with, set this property on the response and set the status to a non-200 value.
                // response.addProperty("invalid", true);

                signature = getV4Signature(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), stringToSign);
            }

            response.addProperty("signature", signature);
            resp.getWriter().write(response.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            resp.setStatus(500);
        }
    }

    // Called by the main POST request handler if Fine Uploader has indicated that the file has been
    // successfully sent to S3.  You have the opportunity here to examine the file in S3 and "fail" the upload
    // if something in not correct.
    private void handleUploadSuccessRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        String key = req.getParameter("key");
        String uuid = req.getParameter("uuid");
        String bucket = req.getParameter("bucket");
        String name = req.getParameter("name");

        resp.setStatus(200);
        System.out.println(String.format("Upload successfully sent to S3!  Bucket: %s, Key: %s, UUID: %s, Filename: %s",
                bucket, key, uuid, name));
    }

    private String getV4Signature(String date, String region, String stringToSign) throws Exception {
        byte[] kSecret = ("AWS4" + AWS_SECRET_KEY).getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] kDate    = sha256Encode(date, kSecret);
        byte[] kRegion  = sha256Encode(region, kDate);
        byte[] kService = sha256Encode("s3", kRegion);
        byte[] kSigning = sha256Encode("aws4_request", kService);
        byte[] kSignature = sha256Encode(stringToSign, kSigning);
        return Hex.encodeHexString(kSignature);
    }

    private byte[] sha256Encode(String data, byte[] key) throws Exception  {
        String algorithm="HmacSHA256";
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(key, algorithm));
        return mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF8"));
    }

    private String hash256(String data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(data.getBytes());
        return bytesToHex(md.digest());
    }

    private String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte byt : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((byt & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();
    }

    private String base64EncodePolicy(JsonElement jsonElement) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        String policyJsonStr = jsonElement.toString();
        String base64Encoded = BinaryUtils.toBase64 (policyJsonStr.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return base64Encoded;
    }

    private String sign(String toSign) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException{
        Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(AWS_SECRET_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA1"));
        String signature = BinaryUtils.toBase64 (hmac.doFinal(toSign.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        return signature;
    }
}
```

My JSP page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="/mysite/uploader/fine-uploader-gallery.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/mysite/uploader/s3.jquery.fine-uploader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/template" id="qq-template-s3">
        <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader qq-gallery" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
            <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
                <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
                <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                <div>Upload a file</div>
            </div>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
                <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
                <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
            </span>
            <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" role="region" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
                <li>
                    <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                    <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector qq-progress-bar-container">
                        <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                    <div class="qq-thumbnail-wrapper">
                        <a class="preview-link" target="_blank">
                            <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="120" qq-server-scale>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">X</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">
                        <span class="qq-btn qq-retry-icon" aria-label="Retry"></span>
                        Retry
                    </button>

                    <div class="qq-file-info">
                        <div class="qq-file-name">
                            <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                            <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                        </div>
                        <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                        <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                        <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">
                            <span class="qq-btn qq-delete-icon" aria-label="Delete"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-pause-selector qq-upload-pause">
                            <span class="qq-btn qq-pause-icon" aria-label="Pause"></span>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-continue-selector qq-upload-continue">
                            <span class="qq-btn qq-continue-icon" aria-label="Continue"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>

            <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>

            <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
                <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
                <input type="text">
                <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                    <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
                </div>
            </dialog>
        </div>
    </script>

    <style>
        #fine-uploader-s3 .preview-link {
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <title>Fine Uploader S3 Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="fine-uploader-s3"></div>

    <script>
        $('#fine-uploader-s3').fineUploaderS3({
                debug: true,
            template: 'qq-template-s3',
            request: {
                endpoint: "my_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com", 
                accessKey: "my_access_key"
            },
            signature: {
                endpoint: "http://www.example.com/uploadfiles"
            },
            uploadSuccess: {
                endpoint: "http://www.example.com/uploadfiles?success",
                params: {
                    isBrowserPreviewCapable: qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews
                }
            },
            iframeSupport: {
                localBlankPagePath: "/server/success.html"
            },
            cors: {
                expected: false
            },
            chunking: {
                enabled: true
            },
            resume: {
                enabled: true
            },
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: true,
                method: "POST",
                endpoint: "http://www.example.com/uploadfiles"
            },
            validation: {
                itemLimit: 5,
                sizeLimit: 15000000
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    notAvailablePath: "/uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png",
                    waitingPath: "/uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png"
                }
            },
            callbacks: {
                onComplete: function(id, name, response) {
                    var previewLink = qq(this.getItemByFileId(id)).getByClass('preview-link')[0];

                    if (response.success) {
                        previewLink.setAttribute("href", response.tempLink)
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A working example can be found in at https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples. Please provide an answer once you have determined what the error is in your code. There isn't much more help anyone can offer since you haven't provided any of your code.

Comment: Hi Ray, tks for your reply.
Sorry about that - please see the code that I'm using on my original post.

Tks in advance.

Comment: Most likely it is a server configuration issue. What does the _exact_ response look like according to your browsers? Include all headers and the response payload

Comment: Hi Ray, Please see the logs and header bellow.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxqQ7Y3DJEziRTBueDVDdExzV2c/view
Tks again.

Comment: I'm unable to locate your server's response to Fine Uploader's signature request in that document.

Comment: Hi Ray, I'm using some extensions on Chrome to get that info.

Please, how I can get the right response? - I'm not familiar considering that my console logs shows that I'm receiving an empty or invalid response from the server. http://imgur.com/mYutCQS

Comment: It will be easiest to use the network tab in chrome dev tools.

Comment: Hi Ray, sounds better now.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxqQ7Y3DJEziNlZ0UmxCbllMUU0/view
Tks in advance.

Comment: Yep, your server isn't returning any data in its response. You'll need to step through the code executed by your server to see why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The answer:

I just changed the endpoint URL in the JSP:

```
signature: {
             endpoint: "http://www.mysite/uploadfiles?status=signature"
            },
            uploadSuccess: {
                endpoint: "http://www.mysite/uploadfiles?status=success",
                params: {
                    isBrowserPreviewCapable: qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews
                }
            }
```

and the condition structure in the Servlet - doPost method:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        if (req.getParameter("status").equals("signature"))
            handleSignatureRequest(req, resp);
        else if (req.getParameter("status").equals("success"))
            handleUploadSuccessRequest(req, resp);
    }
```

Works fine now.